# press any key to rerun the script - powershell

Tags: powershell, restart

I do have a powershell script which contains performing a password reset for single user. Here's the script I made below

```
 Cls 

 $sam = Read-Host -Prompt 'Username?'
 $Pass = 'samplepass123' 

 $Pass1 = ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force

 #Reset the account password
 Set-ADAccountPassword $sam -NewPassword $Pass1 -Reset

 Write-Host $sam,$Pass
```

The problem is, I am searching throughout the internet to **rerun the script by pressing any key from the Powershell CMD** and/or **pressing q to stop the script** but no luck for me.

Thank you in advance who will help on my problem!

Comment: Clearly that would require a loop around the existing code, and the addition of a test to compare the input from the user to `q` to exit that loop before the rest executed, wouldn't it? You'd also need to change your current code from a hard-coded password to ask the user to enter a new password after getting their username.

Comment: Look into the `about_Do` loop documentation

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I've created the script with a do until loop with a function in it to keep the script going and I've decided to go with the read host route. Again, thank you and good day!